# TextArea as Log uses information from another class

Tags: java

I have 2 Classes.

1. GUI (with main method in it)
2. Parser (this reads files(csv), works with them and then writes a new file)

I have a TextArea in my GUI which should be the logwindow.

in this window i want information from my parser class hence i created the following parts:

```
//object that should be accessible from the GUI class
private String logText;

// in this part of the parser class i go through each line of the file 
// i want the first line in my log (next)
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = sc.nextLine();

if(onlyonce=true){
    logText=x;
            onlyonce=false;
}
```

this code enables me to get the first line of code and put it into a private attribute of the class.

how can i get this information into my gui class?

any suggestions.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class MyBean{
  String str;
  int curr,next,prev;
}
```

set value in `parser` class

```
  MyBean objBean = new Bean();
  objBeam.curr=YourValue;...
```

Then Create Object in `GUI`  class and `getvalue` as like as set value. You can also use `getter` `setter` method!

Comment: thank you that worked better then expected since i worried to be forced to create another GUI object resulting in another programstart.